# Setting the color of multiple characters of TextView in java

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, hex

I will do my best to explain my problem, sorry if I am not clear. Basically I want to set the color of individual characters of a text, and then display them in Android App Development Kit. The problem I am having is that I am taking an array of the characters, and don't know how to set the color of them to a certain hexadecimal value.

For instance if the String is "hello". I would want each character to be a different color.

So I would take 'h' and assign it the hexadecimal value of "#000000". And then display it using xml. Is this possible? Here is what I am attempting to do now with my code.

```
 String end = "";
 for (int p = 0; p < charzart.size(); p++) {

       if (charzart.get(p).equals(" ")) {

            }
       else{
            Spannable colorSpan = new SpannableString(charzart.get(p));
            int fake = Integer.parseInt(color.get(p));

            colorSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(fake), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

            end += colorSpan;
                        }


                    }

       output.setText(end);
```

Right now my code doesn't work and I am not sure why. So i am running through charzart which holds my characters. And then attempting to assign the hexadecimal value ( which I have in another array list called color). I check to see if there is a space, if there is I ignore it and move on until i reach a character. From there, I get the character, set it to a spannable. I then get the color, apply it to the spannable, add it to a string and at the end set the TextView to that string.

Basically I want to know how to assign a hexadecimal value to a character, which will then be outputted by XML.

Comment: "And then display it using xml" -- what does this mean? "which will then be outputted by XML" -- what does this mean?

Comment: I want it displayed in an edittext field in my app. The way android app development kit works is that it displays this text field through xml. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: "I want it displayed in an edittext field in my app" -- that may not work the way you want. Usually, this sort of effect is reserved for `TextView`, where the text is static, not `EditText`, where the text is editable. That being said, you would need to use a `SpannableStringBuilder`, wrapping each character in a `ForegroundColorSpan`, specifying the color that you want.

Comment: Hahhaha well crap :/. Sorry I am just getting into app dev. Hmm so say I would want to do that for textview. How could I change the characters to be different colors?

Comment: "How could I change the characters to be different colors?" -- the same way. What makes it complex for `EditText` is figuring out how you want to handle coloring of text changes. Suppose the user puts the cursor between the `h` and the `e` of your `hello`, and then the user starts typing. What happens? Does the new text adopt the color used for `h`? Does the new text adopt the color used for `e`? Does the new text adopt the default color for text? Do you want new colors used for each newly-typed character?

Comment: Cool, I will check out SpannableStringBuilder and ForegroundColorSpan. Appreciate the help!

Comment: How do you apply a hexadecimal value to foregroundcolorspan?

Comment: Assuming that the hex value is a `String`, use [`parseString()` on `Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work. Edited it , can you take a look please? Thank you

Comment: `end` needs to be a `SpannableStringBuilder`. Strings have no formatting.

Comment: says there is an incompatibility in end+= colorSpan; adding an int to a string

Comment: If you look at [the documentation for `SpannableStringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html), you will see that it has a series of `append()` methods for adding new text with spans to it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :/ i put in 'end += SpannableStringBuilder.append(colorSpan);' But it says it cannot reference static content. I understand that you must add a spanner to a spanner, but I don't get why it is not letting me add the two spannables together

Comment: If `end` is a `SpannableStringBuilder`, call `end.append(colorSpan)` to append something to it. In particular, you will find it more efficient to use [the version of `append()` that applies the span as part of appending](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29). You might also consider searching for `spannablestringbuilder example` on your favorite search engine. If you have further questions, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question via the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: i made a new question :( sorry. Can you help?